# Weird y-position offset using custom frag shader (Cocos2d-x)

Tags: c++, opengl-es, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I'm trying to mask a sprite so I wrote a simple fragment shader that renders only the pixels that are not hidden under another texture (the mask). The problem is that it seems my texture has its y-coordinate offset after passing through the shader.

This is the init method of the sprite (GroundZone) I want to mask:

```
bool GroundZone::initWithSize(Size size) {

    // [...]

    // Setup the mask of the sprite
    m_mask = RenderTexture::create(textureWidth, textureHeight);
    m_mask->retain();
    m_mask->setKeepMatrix(true);


    Texture2D *maskTexture = m_mask->getSprite()->getTexture();
    maskTexture->setAliasTexParameters(); // Disable linear interpolation on the mask

    // Load the custom frag shader with a default vert shader as the sprite’s program
    FileUtils *fileUtils = FileUtils::getInstance();
    string vertexSource = ccPositionTextureA8Color_vert;
    string fragmentSource = fileUtils->getStringFromFile(
                            fileUtils->fullPathForFilename("CustomShader_AlphaMask_frag.fsh"));


    GLProgram *shader = new GLProgram;
    shader->initWithByteArrays(vertexSource.c_str(), fragmentSource.c_str());

    shader->bindAttribLocation(GLProgram::ATTRIBUTE_NAME_POSITION, GLProgram::VERTEX_ATTRIB_POSITION);
    shader->bindAttribLocation(GLProgram::ATTRIBUTE_NAME_TEX_COORD, GLProgram::VERTEX_ATTRIB_TEX_COORDS);
    shader->link();
    CHECK_GL_ERROR_DEBUG();
    shader->updateUniforms();
    CHECK_GL_ERROR_DEBUG();

    int maskTexUniformLoc = shader->getUniformLocationForName("u_alphaMaskTexture");
    shader->setUniformLocationWith1i(maskTexUniformLoc, 1);

    this->setShaderProgram(shader);
    shader->release();

    // [...]
}
```

These are the custom drawing methods for actually drawing the mask over the sprite:
You need to know that `m_mask` is modified externally by another class, the `onDraw()` method only render it.

```
void GroundZone::draw(Renderer *renderer, const kmMat4 &transform, bool transformUpdated) {

    m_renderCommand.init(_globalZOrder);
    m_renderCommand.func = CC_CALLBACK_0(GroundZone::onDraw, this, transform, transformUpdated);
    renderer->addCommand(&m_renderCommand);

    Sprite::draw(renderer, transform, transformUpdated);
}

void GroundZone::onDraw(const kmMat4 &transform, bool transformUpdated) {

    GLProgram *shader = this->getShaderProgram();

    shader->use();
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_mask->getSprite()->getTexture()->getName());
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
}
```

Below is the method (located in another class, GroundLayer) that modify the mask by drawing a line from point `start` to point `end`. Both points are in Cocos2d coordinates (Point (0,0) is down-left).

```
void GroundLayer::drawTunnel(Point start, Point end) {

    // To dig a line, we need first to get the texture of the zone we will be digging into. Then we get the
    // relative position of the start and end point in the zone's node space. Finally we use the custom shader to
    // draw a mask over the existing texture.
    for (auto it = _children.begin(); it != _children.end(); it++) {

        GroundZone *zone = static_cast<GroundZone *>(*it);

        Point nodeStart = zone->convertToNodeSpace(start);
        Point nodeEnd = zone->convertToNodeSpace(end);

        // Now that we have our two points converted to node space, it's easy to draw a mask that contains a line
        // going from the start point to the end point and that is then applied over the current texture.
        Size groundZoneSize = zone->getContentSize();
        RenderTexture *rt = zone->getMask();
        rt->begin(); {

            // Draw a line going from start and going to end in the texture, the line will act as a mask over the
            // existing texture
            DrawNode *line = DrawNode::create();
            line->retain();
            line->drawSegment(nodeStart, nodeEnd, 20, Color4F::RED);
            line->visit();

        } rt->end();
    }
}
```

Finally, here's the custom shader I wrote.

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

varying vec2 v_texCoord;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform sampler2D u_alphaMaskTexture;

void main() {

    float maskAlpha = texture2D(u_alphaMaskTexture, v_texCoord).a;
    float texAlpha = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord).a;
    float blendAlpha = (1.0 - maskAlpha) * texAlpha; // Show only where mask is invisible

    vec3 texColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord).rgb;

    gl_FragColor = vec4(texColor, blendAlpha);

    return;
}
```

I got a problem with the y coordinates. Indeed, it seems that once it has passed through my custom shader, the sprite's texture is not at the right place:

Without custom shader (the sprite is the brown thing):

[image: Without custom shader]

With custom shader:

[image: With custom shader]

What's going on here? Thanks :)

Comment: Just skimmed the code. Have you considered that shaders and OpenGL in general work with pixel coordinates, whereas cocos2d works with point coordinates (unless explicitly mentioned in the accessor like positionInPixels)? It seems to be a Retina device, and the offset being 2x as heigh as expected is a clear sign for a point to pixel conversion issue, respectively multiplying with content scale factor where you shouldn't have.

Comment: what tools did you use to write the custom shader?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the solution. The vert shader should not use the MVP matrix so I loaded `ccPositionTextureColor_noMVP_vert` instead of `ccPositionTextureA8Color_vert`.

Comment: woah, spent 2 hours trying to find why my simple shader was messing the scaling + positioning of my sprite. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your vert shader (.vsh), your main method should look something like this:

```
attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord;
attribute vec4 a_color;

varying vec4 v_fragmentColor;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;

void main() 
{                   
    //CC_PMatrix is the projection matrix, where as the CC_MVPMatrix is the model, view, projection matrix. Since in 2d we are using ortho camera CC_PMatrix is enough to do calculations.      
    //gl_Position = CC_MVPMatrix * a_position;

    gl_Position = CC_PMatrix * a_position;
    v_fragmentColor = a_color;
    v_texCoord = a_texCoord;
}
```

Note that we are using `CC_PMatrix` instead of `CC_MVPMatrix`.

Comment: Why after `uv * vec(1.0,-1.0)`, i don't get inverted sprite?